# Reuse LP154WP4-TLA1 LCD screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, hardware, screen

My Dad had a MacBook Pro from late 2008/early 2009 that he used to dualboot Windows XP and MacOS on. It eventually gave up the ghost (sort of) and wouldn't boot from the MacOS partition. Still did XP, for some reason. ???

I recently backed it up for him and he gave it to me to tinker with. I found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY/comments/vcr9ld/using_a_dead_laptopmacbook_screen_as_a_monitor/), [this blog](https://louwrentius.com/recycle-your-old-laptop-display-and-turn-it-into-a-monitor.html), and [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfirQC99xPc) and I think I can do it. I know that I can sell it on Ebay and just buy a regular monitor but I want to do this project.

These are the pictures:

Back:
[image: back of macbook screen]

Front:
[image: front of macbook screen]

Connector:
[image: macbook screen connector]

In the Reddit post I linked above, I found a [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/DIY/comments/vcr9ld/using_a_dead_laptopmacbook_screen_as_a_monitor/icfu1q1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) that said "Look up a driver controller board for the model of display that you want to use. You're probably going to find it on eBay...". I took apart the screen and I successfully got the model number (LP154WP4-TLA1), but I can't figure out how the panel connects to the [driver board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/234457850383). Any ideas? I don't see the port for the LVDS cable anywhere on it.

Comment: The company that provides the driver board includes the cable.  if you look on the image, you'll see the LVDS connector.  This is part of the reason they need to know the *exact* PN# of the display.

Comment: @Allan thank you! Do you know if there is a frame that I can put the LCD panel into (a replacement for the MacBook display assembly)? I can 3D print something if needed but I am not sure how to _make_ a frame for it.

Comment: Frames/enclosures are, for the most part, pretty standard. Where to find them, I would guess eBay/Ali Express.  For the projects I worked on, I used picture frames or had them built out of wood.